# Knitr style table with CSS

Tags: css, r, knitr, r-markdown

I am sure that I am overlooking something obvious, but I want to style my tables produced and `kable` with custom css.

You can find the gist of my  `RMD` and `CSS` files [here](https://gist.github.com/Btibert3/49fa80ec1629090dff7b).

My goal was to leverage some of the Table CSS examples that I found [here](http://www.freshdesignweb.com/free-css-tables.html).

When I run my report, my table looks like this:

[image]

but from the CSS example above, it should look like the image below.

[image]

My question:  What am I missing, or is this level of styling not possible with `RMarkdown`.

My `RMD` file is also shown below:

````
---
title: "Test Table CSS"
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: NULL
    style: flat-table.css
---

I want to be able to style my tables with CSS. From the looks of it, I should be able to do that 
through the use of `CSS` and `knitr:kable`.  


```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
data(mtcars)
mt_head = head(mtcars[, 1:5])
```

I want to be able to style my table just like one found [here](http://codepen.io/njessen/pen/naLCv)


```{r echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
library(knitr)
kable(mt_head, "html", table.attr='class="flat-table"')
```
````

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you take your .Rmd file and the modified CSS file below, you can obtain your desired result with:

```
knitr::knit2html('my-report.RMD', stylesheet = 'flat-table.css')
```

Here's the result:
[image]

Here is an updated **flat-table.css**:

```
.flat-table {
  display: block;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-size: 115%;
  overflow: auto;
  width: auto;
}
  th {
    background-color: rgb(112, 196, 105);
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  td {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    color: rgb(111, 111, 111);
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I started fresh, took your revised CSS (which appears to be an obvious oversight on my part, right) and created a [new github repo here](https://github.com/Btibert3/so-knitr-tables/tree/master).  The fresh repo worked.  Thanks!

Comment: In current builds of Rstudio/pandoc/knitr you can specify CSS in YAML: output:  html_document:  css: flat-table.css

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your answer! I just wonder if it makes sense to add a clause regarding @patrickmdnet 's suggestion regarding YAML css.

Comment: @akhmed Feel free to edit into the answer. I haven't tried that workflow, so I don't know what the correct representation would be.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a small amount of customisation that you want to do, you can consider [including the CSS directly within the RMarkdown file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34022558/7347699). Markdown will pass the CSS directly through provided it is enclosed `<style> </style>`. Here is a full example:

````
---
output: html_document
---

# Test Project

<style>
  .flat-table {
    display: block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: 115%;
    overflow: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  thead {
    background-color: rgb(112, 196, 105);
    color: white;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 20px 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  tbody {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    color: rgb(111, 111, 111);
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
</style>



```{r}
knitr::kable(mtcars[1:5, 1:5])
```
````

[image]

### Advanced Formatting

[This guide](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/) provides lots of useful information on CSS styles for tables. You can achieve some cool things with a few lines of CSS. For example, you can make the row of the table highlight on Hover:

```
tbody tr:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

[image]

Note that a lot of table styles use some form of JavaScript to get the formatting working, and also may make changes which affect the rest of the document. You are best sticking to the `thead` and `tbody` tags.

Answer (score 0):

See [custom blocks](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html):

There is a markdown syntax for adding attributes.

````
::: {#id..class}
```{r showdata}
knitr::kable(yourtable)
```
:::
````

E.g.

````
::: {#table .table .table-bordered}
```{r showdata}
knitr::kable(cars)
```
:::
````