# how can I change how a table looks with knitr

Tags: r, knitr

When I use `knitr` I end up using `xtable` for tables but in html they do not look good:
[image]
How can I make nice line/column line-separated tables

Comment: Pass custom CSS for the tables to the `knit2html` function.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but do you have a working example somewhere ? PS: you can certainly add this as an answer

Comment: You can take a look at this question for a specific example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254552/knitr-style-table-with-css.

Comment: http://blogs.cetis.ac.uk/adam/2013/10/25/changing-style-knitr-and-markdown-in-rstudio/