# Change the default size of the Search Box in DT:: datatable in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, datatable, dt

I have tried searching a method / options in DT::datatable to change the default width of search box. Answers available are for HTML/CSS etc but I am not sure how to incorporate the width = 200px or 200% in options =list(search = list(search="",
width = 200px # or width = "200%" is not working.

```
DT::datatable(
  mtcars,options = list(dom="ft",search =list(search = 'Type here to search',
  width= "200%")))
```

Any guidance on dom elements in DT will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can style RMarkdown in two ways as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24254552/knitr-style-table-with-css) then we can apply a specific style using different CSS selectors i.e. id, class name or even for *inputs* as in our case. Here is a solution include the CSS directly within the RMarkdown file.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document: default
  pdf_document: default   
---
<style>
   h1.title{
        color:red;
   }

   .dataTables_wrapper  .dataTables_filter {
          width: 100%;
          float: none;
          text-align: center; 
          //align the Search box to center. left and right also valid 
   }

   input[type="search"] {
        height: 28px;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
  } 

</style>



```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown
```{r cars}
library(DT)
#summary(cars)
DT::datatable(
mtcars,options = list(dom="ft",search =list(search = 'Type here to search')))
```
````

Comment: Great. Let me check this and the related links shared. Any further ideas on dom elements ? E.g. how to manipulate other elements like i, r, etc. How to align the Search box to Center / Left (default is right).

Comment: @anuanand Please check my update. Other elements can be style as any HTML tags using CSS. Open your document in a browser and use _Inspect_ to understand the document structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me learn this and more of HTML. Seems everything is possible if one is ready to learn..!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing worked for me is this css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#datatable-buttons_filter').css({"position":"relative","left":"-100px"});
});
```

Comment: Can check this. But where to place this code in the Flexdashboard or Shiny in R?

Comment: You can place it in your front end